# Options for Displaying Data in table format

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

[image: Data Representation Format]

Hi

I want to display the data in the format that is represented in the screenshot. All the data that is shown is retrieved from Sql Server-2005 Database. Which is the best option for such kind of data representation? I have read in the forums, from them I could not get a clear perspective. Some were suggesting listview others nested datagrid, some repeater control. Can you please suggest me which one would be a proper and accurate way to go forward ?? Along with some reasons (if possible !!). And I'm using visual studio 2008, .net Framework 3.5, asp.net with c# and I'm NOT using LINQ in my project and it is a web application. The same picture can also be found at http://postimage.org/image/2xj9bdles/

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this with a ListView and nested Gridviews.  There is nothing tricky about it.

I suggest you start with a ListView and just make the parent rows (ie: the grey bar rows.)  From there you can add in your nested GridViews.

Comment: u mean for creating headers I should use ListView and for actual data retrieval and presentation I should use nested gridviews ?

Comment: It all depends on how your data is structured.  Using the data is presented in the image you provided, if your data is stored in a List of invoice objects.  Then you would bind the list of invoices to a ListView.  Each child GridView would have its datasource set to the corresponding invoice and all invoice items would be displayed in the GridView.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just a shot in the dark. Did you try [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) controls? Not free, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I'm faced with data that needs to be represented in a complex table format I default to using the Repeater control. I've even started using Repeater for simple tables as well. Why Repeaters? You get to completely (and easily) control the output. Which allows for some pretty complex arrangements, and also allows for lightweight HTML for simple grids.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to take a look outside of the box. Right now you are only exploring server controls. While convenient, they lack the ability to be customized in a practical manner.

You can easily build this table in your code behind with a string builder with unlimited control and less code.

Here is an example that uses LINQ for the datasource, but you could modify it for yours.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append( "<table class='tableStripe'>");
sb.Append( "<tr><th width='1%'>Active</th><th>Image</th><th>Name</th><th>Short Description</th><th>Source</th><th width='1%'>Date Created</th><th width='1%'>Data Modified</th></tr>");

foreach (var result in join)
{
    string chk = (result.Brand.Active ? "checked='checked'" : "");
    sb.AppendFormat( @"<tr><td><input class='brandChk' value='{4}' type='checkbox' {0}>
                       </td><td width='1%'><img width='50px' src='{1}'</img></td>
                       <td><a href='/admin/Catalog/Brand/Detail.aspx?brandId={4}'>{2} 
                       </a></td><td width='60%'>{3}</td>", chk, result.Brand.Image,
                       result.Brand.Name, result.c,result.Brand.BrandID);
    sb.Append("<td>");
        foreach (var q in result.Sources)
        {
            string srcname = (q.Source1=="Motovicity" ? "Motovicity":"Direct");
            sb.AppendFormat("<img src='{0}' title='{1}'</img>", q.Image,srcname);
        }
        string date = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", result.Brand.DateCreated);
        string mod = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", result.Brand.DateModified);

    sb.Append("</td>");
    sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>", date, mod);
}
sb.Append("</table>");
resultSpan.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
```

This example is a lot more complex than what you're probably looking for, but it should get it's point across.